# How to show *.ipp files inside "Header Files" filter?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing am appplication using Visual Studio, and by desing I have some `*.hpp` and `*.ipp` files.

With the default options, the **Solution Explorer** window don't show `*.ipp` files in the `Header Files` filter. I could use the `Show all files` option but my proyect have lots of dependencies and the list would be very long making difficult for me find the wanted files quickly.

[image: Where to find the "Show all files" option]

Hence the question: *How to show *.ipp files inside "Header Files" filter?*

Answer (score 0):

Making `*.ipp` --or any other file-- appears under the `Header Files` filter is indeed very easy. Just right click on the target filter --this work on any of the filters-- and select `properties` from the popup menu.

On the properties window add the `ipp` entry as showed in the image.

[image]